# How to find the number of times a WebElement is present in the HTML DOM?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a function which returns `WebElement`. Now I need to find out its occurrences or say the times it is present.

E.g.

```
@Test
public void elementCount() {
    navigate("https://www.msn.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a"));
    if (elementCount(element)>0){
        foo();
    } else {
       bar();
    }
}
```

I have another method which takes the parameter as string:

```
public int elementCount(String string) {
    int i = driver.findElements(By.xpath(string)).size();
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.println("Element count is "+i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Element not found);
    }
    return i;
}
```

I need another method which takes `WebElement` as a parameter and gives me the count. I tried to cast it with `By` but it gave me error `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.By` Can't think of anything else.

I am using Windows, Java, Selenium, testNg, Maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List <WebElement> ele=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
System.out.println(ele.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElements(By.xpath(string));` will return the List of WebElements

then you can define the method for like that:

```
public int getCount(List<WebElement> ele){
    if(ele!=null)return ele.size();
    return 0; // or can throw the exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### WebElement

A [**WebElement**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) represents a single *HTML* element within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). So each *WebElement* is unique and it's presence can't be in multiple places in the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

To lookout for an *WebElement* you need to invoke the [`findElement()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("unique_xpath_of_webelement"));
```

But as per your code trial if you want to look for the **number** of any particular tag e.g. `<a>` in that case you have to invoke [`findElements()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method as follows :

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.msn.com");
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
if (elementList.size()>0){
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
```

If you are looking for a method which takes a parameter as `String` you can use the following code block :

```
public int elementCount(String myString) {
    int i = driver.findElements(By.xpath(myString)).size();
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.println("Element count is : "+i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such element found matching the provided xpath");
    }
    return i;
}
```

Now, you can call the method from your `main()`/`@Test` anytime along with the desired `xpath` as :

```
int myCount = elementCount("//*[contains(text(),'paul')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract the locator from an existing element.

In your example, you passed a `String` representing a locator and get a count of found elements. I would suggest that you change that slightly to take a `By` instead.

If you take a `String`, the method will be tied to a certain locator type, i.e. in your case XPath. If you take a `By` locator, you can have a single method that takes any locator type.

I would suggest you change your method to

```
public int elementCount(By locator) {
    return driver.findElements(locator).size();
}
```

If all you want to test is existence of an element (e.g. count > 0, as in your test case), then you can change the above function to

```
public bool elementExists(By locator) {
    return driver.findElements(locator).size() > 0;
}
```

Using this would change your test case to

```
@Test
public void elementCount() {
    navigate("https://www.msn.com");
    elementExists(By.tagName("a")) ? foo() : bar();
}
```